# discord.py - Sending virtual PDF file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is there any way to upload a virtual PDF file onto Discord (I do not want files to be created on my computer). I already know I can send virtual `txt` files with [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) like this:

```py
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from io import StringIO

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, *, string):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(
        fp=StringIO("This is a test"),
        filename="Test.txt"
    )
```

But this doesn't work with PDF files. I tried using [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead but I got no result. Does anyone please know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using [FPDF](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from io import BytesIO
from fpdf import FPDF

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.command()
async def pdf(ctx, *, text):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(40, 10, text)
    bstring = pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1')
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(BytesIO(bstring), filename='pdf.pdf'))

bot.run("token")
```